# how to assign some section of a html code that has ' (single quotation) and "(double quotation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I want to assign section of the html to javascript variabled named `content`,below is the html that I want to assign:

```
<div class="post">
    <div>
        <div class="left-up-image" ><img src="{% static 'social/images/pin.png' %}"></div>
        <div class="right-up-image" ><img src="{% static 'social/images/pin.png' %}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainPost">
        <p >stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="left-down-image" ><img src="{% static 'social/images/pin.png' %}"></div>
        <div class="right-down-image" style=""><img src="{% static 'social/images/pin.png' %}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="friendPostExtra">
        <div class="likePost">
            <img class="likeButton" src="{% static 'social/images/like.png' %}">
            <p>12</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dislikePost">
            <img class="dislikeButton" src="{% static 'social/images/dislike.png' %}">
            <p>12</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commentPostButton">
            <p>Comment</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sharePostButton">
            <p>Share</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to `prepend` this section with jquery when a button clicked.in this section of the html we have both `'` and `"` marks and I can't use it as simple string with `'` or `"` to the jquery variable.how can I do this ?

Comment: There won't be any single quotes after django is done with it, so use single quotes. Your real problem is that it's multiline. Why don't you just put it where it will appear, make it hidden and show it with jQuery?

Comment: You don't have to be consistent in your use of quotes. You can use single quotes in some elements, double quotes in others. All that matters is that they match properly.

Comment: @PavelAnossov because this is the post that created every time that user clicked a some button in the page.then content go to server and check then return to the html page and add content to the page(like facebook,...)

Comment: @Barmar how can I use django static file source in html with only use single quotes ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about django. I'm just talking about HTML in general, and using `jQuery.prepend()`.

Answer (score 0):

either you can escape the quotes

```
var content = "<a href=\"http://..\" alt='something'>link</a>";
```

or you can use this method (i dont know what its called)

```
<script id="testId">
  <a href="http://.." alt='something'>link</a>
</script>

var content = $('script#testId').html();
```

im pretty sure that the second one is some sort of bad codeing practice but i use it for a javascript templating system and it works nicely

Comment: thanks, but your second solution is not for me.because I want to create some content with jquery not get it from DOM.

Comment: where are yopu getting the code above from then as i assume your not creating that snipped with jquery? i just assumed that it was comming from a template file

Comment: yes.it is from template file but I want to create content with jquery not to get it from DOM in your second code you are get `html()` from the DOM.I means this : `var content = $('script#testId').html();`

Comment: so if i have it correct the template will be in a template file and you want to load it straight from said template file into the js variable?

Comment: I don't understand what you say exactly, but I have a `.js` file and an html template in my project and I want to create a section of a template that has `'` and `"` in it with jquery with `append` or `prepend` functions but I can't do this because of multilining and existence of `'` and also `"` together.

Comment: if you want to actually build up the html in jquery then as far as i know your only option would be to escape either ' or " using backslashes (depending on which you use to define your string content)

Answer (score 0):

You can HTML-encode characters `'` to `&#39;` and `"` to `&quot;` or `&#34;`, letting you use quotes inside HTML attributes.

Comment: thanks ,But this means that if I have huge of data I must to convert all of `'` and `"` to what you say ? OMG :D